# Using cachedwithin attribute inside cfquery

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, coldfusion-8

When you use the cachedwithin attribute in a cfquery how does it store the query in memory. Does it store it by only the name you assign to the query? For example, if on my index page I cache a query for an hour and name it getPeople will a query with the same name on a different page (or the same page for that matter) use the cached results or does it use some better logic to decide if it is the same query?

Also, if there is a variable in your query does the cache take into account the value of the variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not only the name -- it's the exact query you're running.

```
<cfquery name="getPeople" cachedwithin=".5" ...>
select name from employee order by name
</cfquery>
```

If you invoke this same query anywhere else in your app, you'll get the cached version if it's within half a day of the first query. But these will hit the database for fresh data:

```
<!--- Different name, same SQL: A new cached query --->
<cfquery name="getEmployees" cachedwithin=".5" ...>
select name from employee order by name
</cfquery>

<!--- Different SQL, same name: Redefining the cached query --->
<!--- Note: As pointed out in comments, it's not really overwriting the old query
      of the same name, but making a new one in the cache. The first one by the
      same name is still in the cache, waiting for eviction. --->
<cfquery name="getPeople" cachedwithin=".5" ...>
select name from employee order by name desc
</cfquery>
```

And yes, it does take a variable into account. If you use `cfqueryparam` -- which you should be doing -- your database will cache the **query plan**, but even using `cachedwithin`, each query with a changed parameter will be treated as different from a query caching perspective. Note that this means if you use `cachedwithin` on a query that runs many times with different parameters, you'll be flooding your query cache with queries that have low cache hit rates.

Comment: so what you are saying is that the 2nd getPeople result set would replace the 1st getPeople result set?

Comment: @Jason, according to the doc, no, since the SQL statement is different although they have the same query name.

Comment: Not the same kind of cache, obviously, but yes. If the DB supports it (SQL Server, e.g.) and you use cfqueryparam, the DB can automatically cache the query plan -- avoiding the necessity of building a new query plan for subsequent queries that are substantially the same (except for parameter changes).

Comment: Yeah, Henry is right. It may have the effect of replacing the first result set on that one page, but really there's just an older cached query still there, waiting to be evicted by age or lack of space. I think running the first or second getPeople queries will result in cache hits.

Comment: use CreateTimeSpan() instead of 0.5, clean and clear, no comments needed.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d4f.html

Answer (score 3):

From http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html

> To use cached data, current query
>   must use same **SQL statement, data
>   source, query name, user name,
>   password**.

So those are the 'keys' that "decide if it is the same query"

variable? yes, as long as you use `<cfqueryparam>`