# Coldfusion query caching with arguments

Tags: sql, caching, coldfusion

If I have the following piece of sql

```
<cfquery name="query" datasource="datasource">   
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field = '#ARGUMENTS.attr#'
</cfquery>
```

will there be a problem if I use the `cachedwithin` my cfquery tag since the query can change based on the user input? (Yes I know its not escaped or anything, but this is merely an example)

Comment: See this question: [using-cachedwithin-attibute-inside-cfquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039991/using-cachedwithin-attibute-inside-cfquery)

Comment: It's looking like it won't be a problem as the post from Avery mentions if I read it correctly.

Comment: No, it won't be a problem. It caches queries that match exactly. Make sure you use `cfqueryparam` with your queries though.

Comment: What sort of problems are you thinking about?

Comment: You should change your query to use `cfqueryparam`.